# What does this function mean? function $$1

Tags: awk

This is the first time I've seen such usage. Unfortunately, I can't find relevant information.

```
awk '{print $$1}'
```

What's `$$1` for? Is it an array?

```sh
$ echo -e "2 2 3 4\n2 22 3 4 5 6\na 2 3" | awk '{print $$1}'
2
22
a 2 3
$ echo -e "2 2 3 4\n2 22 3 4 5 6\na 2 3" | awk '{print $$2}'
2

2
$ echo -e "2 2 3 4\n2 22 3 4 5 6\na 2 3" | awk '{print $$3}'
3
3
3
```

The above are just examples. Note that this is not a single `$`, it's a `$$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Indirect field addressing

Look at this as like this `$($1)`.

So for second line `2 22 3 4 5 6` this command `awk '{print $$1}'` will look at `$1` (first field). It does contain value 2, then the result will be `$2` (second field) so result of `$$1` will be `22`. `$$1` will take the number from field #1 (`$1`) and use this as a field number for the outer `$`.

Example:

```
$ echo -e "1 b c d\n2 b c d\n3 b c d\n4 b c d" 
1 b c d
2 b c d
3 b c d
4 b c d
```

Then:

```
$ echo -e "1 b c d\n2 b c d\n3 b c d\n4 b c d" | awk '{print $$1}'
1  # since filed #1=1 result print first field
b  # since filed #1=2 result print secondfield
c  # since filed #1=3 result print third field
d  # since filed #1=4 result print fourth field
```

Edit
As @kvantour points out, you can add as may $ as you like

```
awk '{print $$$1}' = awk '{print $$($1)}' = awk '{print $($($1))}'
```

And as @Ed points out, you can make it more readable by expand it like this:

```
awk '{print $$1}' = awk '{fieldNr=$1; print $fieldNr}'
```

Comment: Be aware that you can keep on doing this: `$$$1` is also possible, etc ...

Comment: Right, and it's easier to read when written as `awk '{print $($1)}'` as you pointed out or even better with a variable to hold the intermediate value `awk '{fieldNr=$1; print $fieldNr}'`